# Re-Associating a child object to another parent -- Rails (2.3.11) delete has_many associated object without sql operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Given the following definitions

```
Foo
    has_many :bars, :dependent => :nullify, :autosave => false

Bar
    validates_presense_of :foo
    foo_id is not null # database constraint
```

I would like to re-associate a Bar object to a different Foo object. I need it all correctly done in memory so I can render everything in case after all work validation fails.

The problem is when I do something like

```
bar.foo.bars.delete(bar)
bar.foo = other_foo
other_foo.bars << bar
```

I get a failure that at `bar.foo.bars.delete(bar)` a sql update executes nulling out my bar's foo_id property. Therefore sql constraint exception and failure. I instead need it to just work all in memory and fail validation if necessary.

Edit:

The thing is this is all in a transaction so I don't care about db updates, I just don't want them triggering database constraint issues, yet I want my constraints to be present and not allow a null value in the db for my Bar object. When my save executes, if it succeeds, I want my save to re-associate everything as appropriate. If it fails I want my memory model to be in the correctly updated (but not valid) state, this way I can render my page with the updated values and messages that the update failed.

Honestly my main goal is to have the following situation:

before:

```
foo1.bars => [bar1, bar2]
foo2.bars => [bar3]
```

after:

```
foo1.bars => [bar1]
foo2.bars => [bar3, bar2]
```

So my main goal is to solve this problem (in-memory full update of all appropriate objects), if it involves not dealing with re-associating like I already have, I'll accept that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an associated child (bar1) element from the parent's (foo1) collection of bars you can use

```
foo1.bars.delete_if{|b| b.id == bar1.id}
```

This will remove bar1 from the foo1's bars collection but bar1 will remain unchanged in the database because `delete_if` works on the Enumerable on which the HasManyAssociation is built on.

Comment: See amendment to my question.

Comment: mmhhh then my solution should work, you reassign (but not save) the bar to the new foo and then call `hide_bar(bar)` on the old foo. In your view you just use `foo1.visible_bars` instead of `foo1.bars`. But you need to save the state somewhere in your form otherwise it will be lost on the next request. If you want to persist the new state you may want to add an extra column like "temporary_foo_id" which is by default set to null and will be set to an existing foo_id if your validation fails.

Comment: Yea, I can approach it this way if needed... Is there a better way to re-associate child objects? I can't be the first to need to re-associate. What is strange is that :nullify documentation indicates a .save is not invoked on the child object. I assumed that meant no requested db update.

Comment: ok another solution which may work is to use the following: `foo1.bars.delete_if{|b| b.id == bar1.id}` because it should work on the Enumerable and not on the DB association. **Edit** It works ! :)

Comment: Can you post another answer? I am accepting that one as it f-ing works!!!! You just made my day dude.

Comment: Cool. I am still experimenting. delete_if may not properly update the in-memory model.

Comment: You may experience wrong results if you use `.count` on the association etc. if you want to work with the underlying "array" you can use this: `foo1.bars.target.count` because `foo1.bars.target` will give you access to the underlying array so you could even use `foo1.bars.target.delete(bar1)`

Comment: Yea, I think its more to do with me holding two references to the same foo object. But in reality its the same foo record, 2 diff objects. Ugh rails how I love you.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the delete method or just create a `before_destroy` filter. [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Comment: I don't want destroy triggered. Its why I have :dependent => :nullify